# Subscription to an observable not running on the expected thread/dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, reactiveui

In a recent practice to learn ReactiveUI, I wrote a simple timer module to 
create a countdown UI feature. To keep the UI responsive, I introduced some multi-tasking code which is provided below. However the code is not functioning as expected, more specifically not running on the expect thread/scheduler.

I created The `timeoutObservable` to produce a series of `TimeSpan` objects, then I made a subscription to it with a simple lambda expression which changes a property bound to a UI textblock control. I used `SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)` to ensure the subscription code run on the main/dispatcher thread.

WndMainVm.cs

```cs
    public class WndMainVm : ReactiveObject
    {
        public WndMainVm()
        {
            ButtonDisplayString = $"Play! (Timeout: {GameTimeout.TotalSeconds}s)";
            StartGameCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async _ =>
            {
                IsGameStarted = true;
                TimeLeft = GameTimeout;
                var lastRecordTime = DateTime.Now;
                await GameControlInteraction.StartGame.Handle(Unit.Default);
                var timeoutObservable = Observable
                    .Interval(UpdateInterval)
                    .Select(l =>
                    {
                        var newLastRecordTime = DateTime.Now;
                        var newTimeLeft = TimeLeft - (newLastRecordTime - lastRecordTime);
                        lastRecordTime = newLastRecordTime;
                        return newTimeLeft;
                    })
                    .Merge(Observable
                        .Timer(GameTimeout)
                        .Select(l => TimeSpan.Zero))
                    .TakeUntil(ts => ts == TimeSpan.Zero);
                timeoutObservable.
                    SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).
                    Subscribe(ts => 
                        TimeLeft = ts);
                await timeoutObservable;
                await GameControlInteraction.StopGame.Handle(Unit.Default);
                IsGameStarted = false;
            }, this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IsGameStarted).Select(v => !v));

            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.TimeLeft)
                .Select(v => $"Time left: {v.TotalMilliseconds}ms")
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.TimeoutDisplayString, out _timeoutDisplayString, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
        }

        private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _timeoutDisplayString;

        public TimeSpan GameTimeout { get; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        public TimeSpan UpdateInterval { get; } = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);

        [Reactive]
        public bool IsGameStarted { get; set; }

        [Reactive]
        public TimeSpan TimeLeft { get; set; }

        [Reactive] 
        public string ButtonDisplayString { get; set; }

        public string TimeoutDisplayString => _timeoutDisplayString.Value;

        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> StartGameCommand { get; }
    }
```

WndMain.cs

```cs
    public partial class WndMain : ReactiveWindow<WndMainVm>
    {
        public WndMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new WndMainVm();
            this.WhenActivated(d =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.ButtonDisplayString, x => x.BtnPlayStop.Content).DisposeWith(d);
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.TimeoutDisplayString, x => x.TbkTimeDisplay.Text).DisposeWith(d); \\CountDownDisplay

                this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.StartGameCommand, x => x.BtnPlayStop).DisposeWith(d);
            });
        }
    }
```

However when I was testing the code, I found out that the subscription code is always running on a thread from thread pool, causing a `TargetInvocationException`. I know this would happen when you try to change a property of a control from a thread other than main/dispatcher thread, so I wonder if there is something wrong with my code preventing it from executing on the right thread. Currently I tried to bypass this problem by creating a dependent property `TimeoutDisplayString` and it worked fine, but this problem still bewilders me and I really want to find out why.

I'm not very familiar with the async/await keyword, so my guess is that I didn't use them correctly, can anyone kindly have a look at it, point out my error, or provide a better countdown solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when we think we should use `SubscribeOn` we should actually be using `ObserveOn`.

> The SubscribeOn operator is similar, but it instructs the Observable to itself operate on the specified Scheduler, as well as notifying its observers on that Scheduler.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html

Comment: Thank you Rodney, your solution is well appreciated! Placing an `ObserveOn` call before `SubscribeOn` solved the problem; the lambda expression `ts => TimeLeft = ts` now runs on the main/dispatcher thread. But I'm still wondering why `SubscribeOn` could not handle the thread switching on its own. By adding the `ObserveOn` call, a part of heavy-lifting work is transferred to the main/dispatcher thread, which I was trying my best to avoid to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: Actually, using ObserveOn right before the Subscribe call is common practice because it doesn’t transfer any of the heavy-lifting work to the main dispatcher thread at all. The effects of SubscribeOn work upstream (literally from SubscribeOn “up” to the source observable). The effects of ObserveOn work downstream, so any calls “under” ObserveOn will be observed on that thread. And by “observed” we’re talking about OnNext, OnError, and OnComplete.

Comment: It seems I had some misunderstandings about the `SubsribeOn` and `ObserveOn` operator. Besides I shouldn't allow concurrent access to the variable `lastRecordTime`, which is bound to cause problems. Thank you! I've Iearnt much this time.